# Mongo Spark Connector -- Doesn't Parallelize reads

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

Mongo Spark Connector is really easy to use but it doesn't seem to scale up to read Big data.

> Sample Code:

```
  val readConfig = ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> "mongodb://mymongoURI", "database"
"mydb", "collection" -> "mycollection" )) 
    val rdd =  MongoSpark.load(sc, readConfig).withPipeline(Seq(Document.parse("{ $match: { 'dayOfYear': '1'}}")))
    val df = rdd.toDF()
```

I have run the above sample code with different combinations and configuration, but the Mongo connector doesn't seem to support parallel reads. The task is always executed on one Task Node (I have 20 node cluster). This won't work when you want to run across 1 TB of data or more.

Has anyone able to solve this puzzle yet ? Or the way am trying is wrong ?

Comment: what are the `--master` or `--num-executor` prop values?

Comment: The sample code won't do anything as there is no action on the underlying RDD. Collections (such as Dataframes and RDDs) are lazy in Spark, so you need to call an action before it gets partitioned and can be parallelised. See: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions